Androidのバージョンの違いによるWifiアクセスポイントへの接続
現在、指定のWifiのアクセスポイントに接続して通信をするというアプリを作っているのですがバージョン毎に動きが違って困っています
最終的に繋がって通信さえ出来ればいいとは思うのですがテストしていると
Android8,Android12,13は正常動作するのですがAndroid10ではまともに動作しません
どうもプログラムよりもOS上での動作の問題みたいで・・・
Android8
特にメッセージが出ることも無くアクセスポイントに接続して通信可能になる
Android12/13
操作が煩雑になるが、OSの指示のポップアップに従うとアクセスポイントに接続して通信可能になる
下の写真の1～4のように指示が出てくるのでそれに従えば接続出来るようになります

Android10

Android10が困ってしまっていて画面に表示されたアクセスポイントを選択すると「接続しました」となって一見接続されたようになるのですが
アクセスポイントには接続されるのですがTCPのパスは通っておらずconnect出来ません
また、https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lipinic.ping&hl=ja
こちらのサイトからこのアプリをインストールしてpingを打ってみても
Network Is unreachable となってしまいます
接続先のアクセスポイントも、Android10だけ接続を検知出来ず・・・
何かAndroid10だけ特殊な操作が必要だとかあるのでしょうか

"esp32_apppoint" というアクセスポイント名から察するに、一般的な市販の Wi-Fi アクセスポイントとは異なるもののように見えます。Android 側の問題だけでなく、接続先の情報についても詳しく書いておいたほうが回答が付きやすい気がします。
